# Issues with GET method (Web API c# .NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on my first API and I've had some issues so far.

I have a User that has a Profession.

The model for User is:

```
namespace Sims.Models
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            DataUsages = new HashSet<DataUsage>();
        }

        public long IdUser { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionId { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionFieldId { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? UserMail { get; set; }
        public string? UserCompany { get; set; }
        public byte[]? UserPicture { get; set; }

        public virtual Profession UserProfession { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ProfessionField UserProfessionField { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<DataUsage> DataUsages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The model for Profession is:

```
namespace Sims.Models
{
    public partial class Profession
    {
        public Profession()
        {
            ProfessionFields = new HashSet<ProfessionField>();
            Users = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        public int IdProfession { get; set; }
        public string ProfessionName { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<ProfessionField> ProfessionFields { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried many solutions but either the methods doesn't return what I want, either it cannot compile.

For example, the automatically generated EntityFrameworkCore GET method returns information only about the user but the profession is null:

```
{
    "idUser": 1,
    "userProfessionId": 1,
    "userProfessionFieldId": 1,
    "userName": "user_test",
    "userMail": "mail@test.com",
    "userCompany": "TestCompany",
    "userPicture": null,
    "userProfession": null,
    "userProfessionField": null,
    "dataUsages": []
  }
```

The thing is the foreign key isn't null in the MySQL database.

In case, here is the method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
        {
            return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
        }
```

I also tried to include the Profession model like with the following code but I get an object cycle:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
        {
            return await _context.Users.Include(u => u.UserProfession)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

I also tried to Select the data I wanted but with the two following methods, I either got a compiling error stating that "Cannot convert anonymous type to model user", or I got compiling errors about "cannot initialize type "User" with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'"

Here are the respective codes:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
        {
            return await _context.Users
                Select(u => new {
                    u.IdUser,
                    u.UserName,
                    u.UserMail,
                    u.UserCompany,
                    u.UserProfessionId,
                     u.UserProfession
                })
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

and

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
        {
            return await _context.Users
                .Select(u => new User {
                    u.IdUser,
                    u.UserName,
                    u.UserMail,
                    u.UserCompany,
                    u.UserProfessionId,
                    u.UserProfession
                })
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

If you have any ideas, recommendations or advice, I will gladly hear from you.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Don't use EF Entity Classes as DTOs, and don't use `IEnumerable<T>` as a return type. And don't do `= null!;` either.

Comment: _but I get an object cycle_ - Where do you get the cycle? In the serializer?